# How to show the user's selected value as a letter not as a number?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The web application that I am developing right now has something called quiz engine which provides users with short quizzes which consist of one question or more. Now, I have a problem with the RESULTS page that shows in a GridView the 
Question Number, User's Answer and Result. Also this page shows in a DetailsView the Question, four possible answers, correct answer and the answer explanation. The main problem that I have is following:
I set the Correct Answer in the database to nvarchar datatype. and I listed the possble answers as A, B, C and D when the user chooses one of them (for example C), the GridView will show the result (the user's answer) as a number which is 3 not as a letter, while the DetailsView will show the Correct Answer as C. I don't know why.

For creating the Quiz engine, I used [the Toturial in the ASP.NET website](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/building-20-applications/lesson-11-building-a-quiz-engine-1) for creating it.

My ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="resultGrid" runat="server" DataKeyNames="QuestionID" SelectedIndex="0" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="resultGrid_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="555px">
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" CssClass="generaltext" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionID" HeaderText="Question" />
                            <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="CorrectAnswer" HeaderText="Correct Answer" />--%>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserAnswer" HeaderText="Your Answer" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Result" HeaderText="Result" />
                        </Columns>
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" CssClass="boldtext" />
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    </asp:GridView>

                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"
                        SelectCommand="SELECT [Question], [Answer1], [Answer2], [Answer3], [QuestionID], [QuestionOrder], [Answer4], [CorrectAnswer], [AnswerExplanation], [QuizID] FROM [Question] WHERE ([QuizID] = @QuizID) ORDER BY [QuestionOrder]">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:SessionParameter Name="QuizID" SessionField="QuizID" Type="Int32" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:DetailsView ID="answerDetails" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"
                        GridLines="None" Height="45px" Width="552px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                        AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="QuestionID">

                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" CssClass="generaltext" />
                        <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#E9ECF1" Font-Bold="True" CssClass="boldtext" Width="100px" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Question" HeaderText="Question" 
                                SortExpression="Question" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer1" HeaderText="A" 
                                SortExpression="Answer1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer2" HeaderText="B" 
                                SortExpression="Answer2" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer3" HeaderText="C" 
                                SortExpression="Answer3" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer4" HeaderText="D" 
                                SortExpression="Answer4" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="CorrectAnswer" HeaderText="Correct Answer" 
                                SortExpression="CorrectAnswer" HeaderStyle-BackColor="lightgreen" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="AnswerExplanation" HeaderText="Explanation" 
                                SortExpression="AnswerExplanation" HeaderStyle-BackColor="lightgreen" />
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DetailsView>
```

My code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ArrayList al = (ArrayList)Session["AnswerList"];

        if (al == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        }

        resultGrid.DataSource = al;
        resultGrid.DataBind();

        // Save the results into the database.
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            // Calculate score
            double questions = al.Count;
            double correct = 0.0;


            for (int i = 0; i < al.Count; i++)
            {
                Answer a = (Answer)al[i];
                if (a.Result == Answer.ResultValue.Correct)
                    correct++;
            }

            double score = (correct / questions) * 100;
            string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString().Replace("ARAMCO\\", "");
            SqlDataSource userQuizDataSource = new SqlDataSource();
            userQuizDataSource.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnectionString"].ToString();
            userQuizDataSource.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO [UserQuiz] ([QuizID], [DateTimeComplete], [Score], [Username]) VALUES (@QuizID, @DateTimeComplete, @Score, @Username)";

            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("QuizID", Session["QuizID"].ToString());
            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("DateTimeComplete", DateTime.Now.ToString());
            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("Score", score.ToString());
            userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("Username", username);

            int rowsAffected = userQuizDataSource.Insert();
            if (rowsAffected == 0)
            {
                // Let's just notify that the insertion didn't
                // work, but let' s continue on ...
                errorLabel.Text = "There was a problem saving your quiz results into our database.  Therefore, the results from this quiz will not be displayed on the list on the main menu.";


            }

        }


    }

    protected void resultGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "QuestionOrder=" + resultGrid.SelectedValue;
    }
```

**SO HOW TO FIX THIS PROBLEM?**

Comment: What are the real values of Answer.CorrectAnswer property? Are they numbers or letters?

Comment: Sorry may I got you wrong: in the database, I have five columns which are: Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4 and Correct Answer. In the first four answers, you can put any text. For the Correct Answer, you just need to put A, B, C or D. and this is what should be displayed in under the User Answer field in the GridView as explained above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to fetch all question and Answer in One datatable/ Array List.
And then bind it in form one by one. Suppose you are in First question and it's Correct answer is D then and user select B that time flag for first question is false. And if it's answer is correct then set flag to true. do this process in all question. After finishing exam you can create result using that flag.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to maintain array for Question and answer.For Eg. You have to create array for Question,answer and Selected Answer. When User change option and submit that time check selected option is right or Wrong. If selected Answer is correct then set flag (Selected Answer) to true. And After completion of Exam you have to generate result using that Array.

I have also done this application using this way....

May be this help to you...
If you have any query then ask me.....

Comment: Showing A, B, C and D in the User's Answer field does not need to do all what you mentioned above.

Comment: Add one more column for Flag which is default False and Change it after Submit answer.